# How to change language of termDocumentmatrix in R text-mining?

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining

### I need to change language to Turkish in the function of termDocumentmatrix. Could you possibly help me?

## this code works. I reach result what i want for stemming, stopwords etc for Turkish.

```
dat<-"BirGün, Türkiye'de günlük olarak yayımlanan ulusal bir gazete.
Gazetenin yazı işleri müdürü Berkant Gültekin, yayın danışmanı Barış İnce, 
sorumlu müdürü Cansever Uğur ve haber koordinatörü İbrahim Varlı'dır. Yayın 
hayatına 14 Nisan 2004'te başlayan gazetenin sahibi Birgün Yayıncılık ve İletişim Ticaret AŞ'd"

dat%>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE)%>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords("tr", source = "stopwords-iso")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem(language = "turkish") %>%
  tokens_tolower() 

Result:

[1] "birg"        "türkiye'"    "günlük"      "yayımlana"   "ulusal"      "gaze"        "gazete"      "yaz"         "iş"         
[10] "müdür"       "berkant"     "gültek"      "yay"         "danışma"     "barış"       "ince"        "sorumlu"     "müdür"      
[19] "cansever"    "uğur"        "haber"       "koordinatör" "ibrah"       "varlı'"      "yay"         "hayat"       "nisa"       
[28] "te"          "başlaya"     "gazete"      "sahip"       "birgi"       "yayıncılık"  "iletiş"      "ticaret"     "aş'd"
```

**But, i dont integrate these processes into term document matrix which is below that i try to mine pdf file**

```
library(pdftools)
library(tm)
library(SnowballC)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(tidytext)
library(quanteda)
```

## this part is reading pdf file in the working place

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")
file<-as.character(files)
opinions <- lapply(files, pdf_text)
length(opinions)
lapply(opinions, length)
```

## creating corpus

```
corp <- Corpus(URISource(files),
               readerControl = list(reader = readPDF))
```

## in this part, "language="turkish" does not working, it still uses base language which is English

```
opinions.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, 
                                   control = 
                                     list(language="turkish",
                                          stopwords = TRUE,
                                          removePunctuation = TRUE,
                                          tolower = TRUE,
                                          stemming = TRUE,
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                          bounds = list(global = c(1, Inf)))) 

inspect(opinions.tdm[1:10,]) 

opinions.tdm <- TermDocumentMatrix(corp, 
                                   control = 
                                     list(language="turkish",
                                          stopwords = TRUE,
                                          tolower = TRUE,
                                          stemming = TRUE,
                                          removePunctuation=TRUE,
                                          removeNumbers = TRUE,
                                          bounds = list(global = c(1, Inf))))
```

```
findFreqTerms(opinions.tdm, lowfreq = 100, highfreq = Inf)

ft <- findFreqTerms(opinions.tdm, lowfreq = 100, highfreq = Inf)
as.matrix(opinions.tdm[ft,]) 

ft.tdm <- as.matrix(opinions.tdm[ft,])
sort(apply(ft.tdm, 1, sum), decreasing = TRUE)
a<-sort(apply(ft.tdm, 1, sum), decreasing = TRUE)
a<-as.data.frame(a)
a$word<-rownames(a)
aa<-a %>%  filter(a > 200) %>%
  mutate(word = reorder(word, a))
```

Comment: The language setting in the control options of TermDocumentMatrix do not support Turkish. If quanteda is delivering what you need, why are you also trying to use tm? For reading in the pdf, you can use the package readtext, that was developed by the same developers as quanteda and do everything with that.

Comment: thanks your comment. I'm new in text mining. I have to convert corpus into termdocumentmatrix in order to use random forest algorithm. can i follow these step with readtext and quanteda package?

Answer (score 0):

Basicly the following will get you to the end quanteda. You might add some lines for extra text cleaning. The advantage of quanteda (and ranger below) is that they run in parallel automatically. With quanteda you can use `quanteda_options(threads = x)` to run on x cores. Default is 2.

```
library(readtext)
library(quanteda)
library(stopwords)

files <- list.files(pattern = "pdf$")

# use option encoding = "UTF-8" if you encounter encoding issues
dat <- readtext(files)

my_dfm <- dat %>% 
  corpus() %>% 
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_tolower() %>%  
  tokens_remove(stopwords("tr", source = "stopwords-iso")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem(language = "turkish") %>% 
  dfm()
```

Next you can use the `convert` function from quanteda to transform the dfm into whatever you need as input for a randomForest. Read the help with the convert function. Note that quanteda itself already contains naive bayes. But to give you an example for a randomForest with the ranger package for speed.

```
# transpose the document term matrix into a term document matrix. 
x <- t(convert(my_dfm, to = "matrix")) 
# transform into data.frame. 
my_df <- data.frame(features = rownames(x), x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) 

library(ranger)
ranger(features ~ ., data = my_df)

Ranger result

Call:
 ranger(features ~ ., data = my_df) 

Type:                             Classification 
Number of trees:                  500 
Sample size:                      2547 
Number of independent variables:  6 
Mtry:                             2 
Target node size:                 1 
Variable importance mode:         none 
Splitrule:                        gini 
OOB prediction error:             100.00 %
```

Comment: thanks phiver. I used ranger package. But now, i have new questions. In the ranger result: Sample size 1536, Number of independent variables: 14427, OOB prediction error: 37.17 %, Mtry: 120 . So, first question is:  Is there any problem in the result? second one is: How can i integrate this result to sample? That is, i want to use this result to classification for new texts. There are lots of customer texts and three main cluster "suggestion", "complaint" and "demand". I want to cluster with respect to the result whenever new ticket comes. How can i do this?

Comment: For the use case you are describing, topicmodels might be a better solution. Check the topicmodels package for more info.